# gitolite git user asking for password with valid keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, gitolite

My gitolite installation start to ask for password suddendly, I checked the `/var/log/secure` file and found this.

```
 sshd[9071]: User git not allowed because account is locked
 sshd[9072]: input_userauth_request: invalid user git
```

After a quick search i've read that the solution is

```
 sudo passwd -u git
```

But this gaves this answer:

```
 Unlocking password for user git.
 passwd: Warning: unlocked password would be empty.
 passwd: Unsafe operation (use -f to force)
```

I used -f to check and yes, it fixed the issue. But is there a security downside of doing this? I dont want this account to have a password, only use keys authentification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security downside is that now your `git` user has no password, and anybody can log in to it without a password (or a key)!

To resolve the problem, the account should not be locked, but *should* have a password, even if nobody ever uses the password. Set a random password for the account, and make sure the ssh keys are working correctly.

Comment: I tried and was not able to login. It asks for password, I press enter key and say pwd is not valid.